# R: Parallel second largest value from multiple vectors

Tags: r

Hi My dataframe looks like this. The rightmost column is my desired column.

```
    Name   Fund-A    Fund-B  Fund-C   SecondLargest(Desired)
    John    30000    20000   10000     20000
    Tom     NA       40000   15000     15000
    Sarah   5000     NA      NA        NA
    Kate    NA       NA      NA        NA
```

I just want the second largest value among Fund-A,Fund-B and Fund-C.If there is no second largest, I can live with an NA,blank or a zero.  I know that "pmax" will give me highest parallel value. I dont know how to get the second highest value.Kindly help. Your help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: reshaping to long format would be another option, it may be slower on large datasets. `library(dplyr);library(tidyr); bind_cols(df1, add_rownames(df1, var= 'rn')  %>% gather(Var, Val, matches('Fund')) %>% group_by(rn) %>% arrange(desc(Val)) %>% slice(2L) %>% ungroup() %>% select(Val))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
R> apply(tbl[,2:4], 1, function(x) x[rank(1/x) == 2])
#[1] 20000 15000    NA    NA
```

which can then be assigned to your object normally, e.g. as in @akrun's answer.

---

```
tbl <- read.table(
  text = "    Name   Fund-A    Fund-B  Fund-C   SecondLargest(Desired)
    John    30000    20000   10000     20000
    Tom     NA       40000   15000     15000
    Sarah   5000     NA      NA        NA
    Kate    NA       NA      NA        NA",
  header=TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: @akrun Thank you! It took me a couple of minutes to realize that `rank` was ranking things in *ascending* order...

Comment: @akrun  Thanks a lot guys. can you kindly educate me about what 1/x is doing here? I am very new to R. Thanks.

Comment: @gibbz00 It is a way to rank in a descending way so that we can call the 2nd.  By dividing `1/x` we get the largest number smallest and smallest largest.  You could also do it by `x[rank(-x)==2]` .  When you stuck on a code, it is better to break it to individual components to see what the result is. For example `apply(df1[-1], 1, rank(1/x))` and `apply(df1[-1], 1, rank(x))`,

Comment: @akrun Thank you for the explanation. Applying the solution and attaching SecondLargest to the dataframe gives me the the df$SecondLargest as a list, not a numeric vector. How do I solve this?

Comment: @akrun I tried as.numeric(apply(tbl[,2:4], 1, function(x) x[rank(1/x) == 2])). But it gives me (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: @gibbz00 Is your object a `data.table` or a `data.frame`?

Comment: @akrun Hey guys, I found the reason. Its about how the function deals with a tie. When there are ties, I get numeric(0) in the SecondLargest column. Kindly let me know how to deal with the situation.

Comment: May be try with `apply(tbl[,2:4], 1, function(x) x[rank(1/x, ties.method='first')==2])`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df1$SecondLargest <- apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) c(x[is.na(x)], sort(x))[2])
```